# Multiple if statement in list comprehension

Tags: python

I have a python list that needs to be converted to a tuple, I also need to add a additional check to check the list element type and convert them to tuple

for example:

```
row_data = ['map',[10,20]]

row_data = tuple(d._get_pk_val() if hasattr(d, '_get_pk_val') else d if type(d) is list else d for d in row_data)
print row_data
```

**result 
row_data == ('map', [10, 20])**

```
Expected result

row_data == ('map', (10, 20))
```

Need to add multiple ifs within the list comprehension and each having its own output.

Comment: There is a point at which list comprehensions become too long and complex to be really readable. Maybe this is one of those occasions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work -

```
row_data = ['map',[10,20]]

row_data = tuple(d._get_pk_val() if hasattr(d, '_get_pk_val') else tuple(d) if type(d) is list else d for d in row_data)
print(row_data)

Output: ('map', (10, 20))
```

Comment: It works..jus wondering how tuple(d) is returned, first it checks for hasattr and then does it check for second if stmt?